# Is it possible to override print_r's behavior on an ArrayIterator object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a PHP class which extends [ArrayIterator](http://php.net/class.arrayiterator), and has all the necessary methods implemented so that it behaves like an array.

This works fine for things like `foreach` loops, but calling [`print_r`](http://php.net/print-r) on it still prints out the object's variables, rather than printing it as it would an array.

Is there some way of overriding this behaviour so that calling `print_r` (and I guess `var_dump`) will print custom output for this object?

Comment: For what it's worth:  http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because it is designed to give **information** about the variable (i.e. it is used for debugging) and not just to give some string representation of it.

You can overwrite [**`__toString`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) though and use `echo`.

Answer (score 6):

Since PHP 5.6 the magic method `__debuginfo` has been added, if you implement it you should be able to overrite the `var_dump` and `print_r` behavior.

seh here:
http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php#object.debuginfo

Answer (score 1):

If don't think it is, unless using [`PHP Runkit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) but I wouldn't recommend this as it would change the expected behavior that your user will expect.

another good way would be to make your own function (e.g.: `my_print_r() { /* some code */ }` or use the `__toString()` magical method.

What is it for ?

Comment: I've modifed some existing code to return an ArrayIterator rather than an actual array for various reasons.  I've got a bunch of tests/debug utils which assume they're getting an array, so I was hoping the new ArrayIterator based class could mimic an array in every way to keep them working as is.

Comment: Hummm, ok. So the fact that `print_r` doesn't really print the same thing isn't breaking your code, you just want your debug display not to be changed.

Comment: At the moment, yes.  I was hoping it was possible to make an object be treated like an array in every respect.  I've got some code which has always returned an array, but now (in some cases) needs to return a object which is a wrapper around an iterable c data structure.

Comment: Maybe the flaw in your code is to have function that have different type returns.

Comment: Yeah, seems the solution will be to wrap normal arrays in an object, and always return that, rather than trying to disguise another object as an array.

Answer (score 1):

And why don't you use the [getArrayCopy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.getarraycopy.php) method?

ie.

```
print_r($yourIterator->getArrayCopy());
```